# How to trigger an event on exit of div container using jquery

Tags: jquery

So, I have a working version of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/yEmvm/19/

When you click on the company of the first address block and then click on the name it fires the event and says invalid address. I don't want to fire that event until I cilck on company for the second address block or anywhere *outside* that first address block. I cannot figure out another event to trigger this on.

This is just an example. This page will contain an unknown number of address blocks from 3 to 99. Also, it will contain many more fields for a full address. The user can keep adding more with a button. However, class and id name structure is consistent.

Comment: blur() does not work on div containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run your code in a timeout, and cancel timer on focus:

```
$('.address').each(function()
{
    var timer;

    $(this).find('input').blur(function()
    {
        timer = setTimeout(function()
        {
            var verified = false; // run your verification here

            if ( ! verified )
            {                
                // run code here to display error
            }
        }, 0);
    })
    .focus(function()
    {
        timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    });
});​
```

Here's a very basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/U6TRj/3/

---

**Explanation:**

Basically, if you're clicking on an `input` element while being focused on another `input`, the browser will first fire the `blur` event on the old element, then the `focus` event on the new element.

What we're doing here with the `timeout` (no delay required), is pushing the execution of the code down the stack, so that it executes after the `focus` event handler. That way, we can cancel it's execution from within the `focus` callback.

Comment: That looks promising. However, the verify is not on an input level but on the block level. Meaning, once the address is completely filled out  and the user exits that address block I want to fire the event which will first save the address to the database with another ajax call and then check with FedEx to ensure the address is valid with yet another ajax call. If not, display invalid icon with address options from fedex, if it is valid display the "saved icon".  So, because it is so intensive, I don't want it to ever fire more than it absolutely has to.

Comment: However... thinking about it... this is also very useful for my field level validation, which there will be too because I don't want to fire the main event described in my above comment until all the fields validate.

Comment: @sabithpocker - I added a brief explanation.

Comment: @BrandonBearden - No trouble. Just move the validation inside the timeout function. I updated the code above, as well as the fiddle linked.

Comment: @JosephSilber That was a fantastic answer :)

Comment: Okay, this works perfectly for the `input` fields on the form. It even gives me my two levels of validation which is even better than I hoped for. Now though I cannot seem to understand how to add the select box for the state to this snippet. Meaning, this works for all `input` types, but not `select` boxes.

Comment: @BrandonBearden - Just change the selector from `find('input')` to `find('input, select')`.

Answer (score 1):

This is behavior is noted on the jQuery API documentation for .focusout()
http://api.jquery.com/focusout/#dsq-comment-108827731

Perhaps the plugin suggested there could help your problem:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/focus